# Who modifies `/etc/init.d/.depend.start` in openSUSE 11?

Tags: boot, opensuse, dependencies, init

Where are the dependency data taken from? Which process modifies the `.depend.*` files and under which circumstances does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

> Which process modifies the .depend.* files and under which circumstances does this happen?

This is the service `insserv` which generates them at every execution based on information get on the whole system like library executable or boot time script.

Comment: It seems to me that there is a part of the question that request which process modifies .depend.* and my answer is more about that part. And this indication allow to read `man insserv` which is quiet complete about what that service rely on and it depend on the configuration you give I can't answer that

Comment: @Mokubai, with only 1 rep, they have no choice but to either chime in with an answer or not contribute at all. `:-|` Also, Kiwy is correct, their post does indeed answer part of the question—though Kiwy, if you can update your post to answer the part about the data source, then it will be even better and probably be up-voted and accepted. `;-)`

Comment: @Synetech thanks for the support. I indeed do not know on what rely `insserv` to generate those script and it's a pretty complicated binary.